# Replace spaces and tabs at the end of the line in all files

Tags: linux, command-line, replace

I need to replace all unwanted spaces in all files from the current directory and from directories from the current directory (recursive search).

I define the *unwanted spaces* the spaces and tabs that are at the end of the line and are not followed by any other character than `\n` (the new line character).

e.g.:

```
This is a line with unwanted spaces    
        // this line is supposed to contain only spaces
Another line without unwanted spaces
Another line with unwanted spaces
```

This snippet will become:

```
This is a line with unwanted spaces

Another line without unwanted spaces
Another line with unwanted spaces
```

How can I remove all unwanted spaces from all files (recursive search) from the current directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should suit your needs:

```
find -type f -exec sed -i 's/[[:blank:]]\+$//' {} \;
```

Note that sed's `-i` option is not safe with symlinks -- it will break them. If this is a problem, consider using `ed` or `ex`.

Comment: Does this enter in hidden files/directories?

Comment: @Johnツ Yes, it does. If you don't want that, you can use `-not -path '*/\.*'`.

Comment: How can I ignore binary files (pem, image files, compiled files etc)?

Comment: `pem` is not a binary file. Either way, the better way is to include what you actually need -- use `-name`, `-iname`, or similar.